# determining reflective, symmetric, transitive, anti-symmetric properties and describing equivalence classes

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations, symmetry

The question: determine if p is reflective, symmetric, transitive and/or anti-symmetric, if p is an equivalence relation, describe the equivalence classes

A = Z , and $apb$ if and only if $5 | (2 a + 3 b )$

This is what i have done:

reflexive: if a,b are an element of integers $2*5 + 3*1 = 13$ and this is not a multiple of 5
therefore $apb$
therefore is not reflective.

symmetric: if $apb$, $5|(2a+3b)$ 
therefore $5|(3b+2a)$ therefore $bpa$ therefore symmetric

transitive: if $apb$ then  $bpc$
$5|(2a+3b)$ Then $5|(3b + c)$

therefore $5|[(2a+3b)+(3b+c)] = 2a+c$ therefore $apc$

and since the relation is not reflexive there is no equivalence relation.

I think ive done transitive wrong, the numbers with throw me off. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: reflexive, sorry it has been a long few days hahaha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: I think you misunderstood the relation. The relation statement is this:
\begin{equation}
aPb\Longleftrightarrow5|(2a+3b)
\end{equation}
$a$ and $b$ are just placeholders. You can think of $P$ like a relation between two objects, lke so:
\begin{equation}
\heartsuit P\diamondsuit\Longleftrightarrow5|(2\heartsuit+3\diamondsuit)
\end{equation}

Read it carefully and pay attention to the roles of $a$ and $b$ (or, equivalently, $\heartsuit$ and $\diamondsuit$) in the definition. To check properties, you must properly write down the relation.

1) reflectivity: $aPa\Longrightarrow\cdots$

2) symmetry: $aPb\Longrightarrow\cdots$

3) transitivity: $aPb,\ bPc\Longrightarrow\cdots$

Comment: hmm so like for example, symmetry: $a$ is related to $b$ if and only if $5|(2a+3b)$ and therefore $b$ is related to $a$ if and only if $5|(2a+3b)$

Comment: No, the order of $a$ and $b$ changes! $aPb$ iff $5|(2a+3b)$, so $bPa$ iff $5|(2b+3a)$.

Comment: I see, so for reflectivity would it be $aPa$ if and only if for all $a$, $5|(2a+3a)$

Comment: exactly. that's the way to go!